# How can I configure salesforce to notify a customer case contact when an internal support rep sends in a email updating the ticket?

Tags: email, email2case, email-alert

I'm using SalesForce for case management.  When I respond to customers through salesforce.com from my Desktop, I can send emails / case comments and they are sent from our support address (supportexample@company.com).   This works out great because the customer can then reply back to the email address that Salesforce monitors and the ticket stays updated.

I want to respond to customers cases while out and about WITHOUT sending from my individual email address.  Is there a way to do this?  The phone itself can't send emails from supportexample@company.com   As far as I can tell, the mobile SalesForce 1 mobile app doesn't allow me to send new case comments or email.  I can only view old ones.

My old ticketing system let me send emails into supportexample@company.com and generated a update notification email to the case contact with the full message included.  I'd like to do something similar.

I was initially thinking I could do this via a workflow rule for the `Email Message` object.  The basic config would be something like:

- Check if email from contains `@company.com` AND message is not in a queue.
- If both conditions are met, initiate an `Immediate Workflow Action` - specifically `New Email`
- Have the `New Email` action send a template with a message body variable including the prior email.

I've hit a snag though: I don't see the option for `New Email` when clicking `Add Workflow Action`. I see it for OTHER workflow rule types but not when the workflow rule object is `Email Message`.  I'm guessing that SalesForce doesn't allow an incoming email to trigger another outbound email alert as part of a workflow rule.

If that's the case, is there another way I can accomplish this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [detailed tutorial](http://clicksandcode.blogspot.com/2014/07/case-comment-in-salesforce1.html) that explains how to create a custom publisher action for Case Comments. Once you complete all the steps, the Case Comment shows up as a publisher action as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a case comment from Salesforce1 mobile app. It automatically shows up in the list of publisher actions in the action bar at the bo, when you are viewing the case. I have only validated this on iOS, but it likely works on Android too. So case comment notification should take care of sending email to customer.

Comment: Strange.  I must be missing something as I don't see that option.  Can you please describe the steps to get there or provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Actually I dug deeper and found that ability to add case comments was a custom publisher action created in our org. So one solution for you will be to create a custom publisher action for this purpose.

Thanks,
Nirav